# can the period an automorphism of an abelian group be unbounded?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

Suppose we have a countable abelian group $A$. Let $\phi$ be an automorphism of $A$.
Let $P = \{ a \in A \mid \exists n \in \mathbb{N}, \text{such that } \phi^{n} (a) =a \}$ be the sets of periodic points of $\phi$  in $A$.

For $a \in P$, let $m_a$  be the smallest positive integers such that $\phi^{m_a} (a) =a$.

**Question:** Is it possible that $\{m_a \mid a \in P\}$ is unbounded?

**Thoughts:** If A is finitely generated abelian, then by the fundamental theorem of finitely generated abelian groups the period must be bounded. I was wondering if this also holds for the countable abelian groups?

Comment: Surely the restricted direct product of countably many copies of any finite abelian group has automorphisms that permute the free factors with arbitrarily long cycles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, *every* infinite abelian torsion group $A$ has such automorphisms. As a rough sketch, if each $p$-component is finite, you may find an automophism of order at least $p-1$ on each of these (nontrivial) components and paste them together to form the desired map.

Otherwise, $A$ has some infinite $p$-component, so we may as well assume that $A$ itself is $p$-primary. If the exponent of $A$ is infinite, multiplication by (e.g.) $p+1$ will to the job. On the other hand, if the exponent is finite, $A$ is a sum of cyclic groups, of which at least one type must appear infinitely often. On this direct summand $C_{p^n}^{\oplus I}$ we may then take any permutation of the summands that has unbounded finite cycles and obtain such an automorphism this way.

(Note that the same is not true for all torsion free groups, as there are arbitrarily large rigid examples, i.e. groups whose only automorphisms are $\pm \mathrm{id}$.)

Answer (score 4):

Take the direct sum of $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ over all the primes, and then take the automorphism of it that is coordinate-wise an order $p-1$ automorphism in each point (i.e. multiply by a generator of $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^\times)$. Then we get elements of arbitrarily high period, since the element which is $0$ in every coordinate but the $p$th coordinate and $1$ in the $p$th coordinate is then periodic of order $p-1$.